# angular 2 select element trigger onchange

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a select element defined as follows:

```
<form #empForm="ngForm" novalidate>
    <div>
        <label>Role</label>
        <select name="role" [(ngModel)]="user" (ngModelChange)="get1($event)" (change)="get($event)">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

And in the .ts,
Since the select html is bounded to the property user, setting it to different values programmatically as follows does not trigger the ngModelChange or change event which i believe is triggered solely based on user intervention

```
  set(input: any) {
    this.user = "3";
  }
```

I wish to trigger those events when the model changes programatically. Is that possible?

Thank you,
Ashley

Comment: can i know the reason why you need to call these methods you can get the change in the component if the user changes and act accordindly

Comment: good question. I have a requirement whereby when the page loads for the first time, I need to set a default value and based on that value, I need to do  some logic. any advice on this?

Comment: So when the page loads for first time means onNgOnInit , you  can take the value in component and then make use of it it will be easier why complicate things

Answer (score 0):

Try adding value Attributes like `<option value="1">`

Answer (score 0):

When the page loads and you set the default value, take it from there and do the logic. No need to read it via your element after you set it.